# Create a folder and subfolders with increase version numbers

Tags: python

I'm creating a folder with Python. Main folder name is 20151104 (YMMDD) and I'm creating subfolder 20151104_version1 (YMMDD_version1).

```
20151104 (mainfolder)
|->20151104_version1 (subfolders)
|->20151104_version2
|->20151104_version3
|->20151104_version4
|->20151104_version5
.........
```

[image: example]

When I restart the Python program, it must create another subfolder and subfolder 20151104_version number must increase. How can I do this?

Comment: so basically you need a new subfolder (with the next version number) created in the main folder each time you run the script?

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right this is what you can do:

```
from glob import glob;
from os import mkdir;
from os.path import curdir, join;

subfolders = glob( join(curdir, 'mainFolder', '*version*') );
subfolers.sort();
currentVersion = subfolers[-1].split('version')[1];
nextVersion  = int(currentVersion ) + 1;

mkdir( join(curdir, 'mainFolder', '20151104_version%d' % nextVersion) )
```